# SQL Server 2008r2 foreign key allowing space

Tags: sql-server

In our database we have two tables linked together. `Table A` has a primary key and `Table B` has a foreign key back to `Table A`'s primary key field.  It is a one-to-many relationship.

Here is my issue:

If I edit `Table B`'s foreign key field by adding a space after the end of the text, it does not prevent that.  This creates the illusion of duplicate values.  (adding any other character is prevented).

How can I make sure that this does not happen again as it will mess up our reporting?

Comment: What is the data type of table A's primary key?

Comment: Well `string` and `string    ` are not the same value.

Comment: the data type is nvarchar. Also, if the values are in 'table A' are supposed to limit what is entered in 'Table B', then how does it allow 'string ' to be entered into 'Table B'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may seem weird, but this is how string comparison should work, as defined by the SQL-92 stanard and implemented by SQL Sever. I got bitten by a few mysterious bugs before I learned this painful lesson. See Microsoft Support: [How SQL Server Compares Strings with Trailing Spaces](http://support2.microsoft.com/kb/316626).

Oracle doesn't compare strings this way and it's a common problem for people migrating from Oracle to SQL Server.

If this is only affecting your reports, I suggest that you trim the string in the `SELECT` clause:

```
SELECT LTRIM(RTRIM(MyColumn)) FROM MyTable
```

Comment: while the 'Select' clause would be great in reporting, that is not the only thing affected. This issue messes with the referential integrity of the db.

Comment: From SQL Server's perspective, there's no issue with referential integrity because these values are equal. SQL is a an IBM product developed in the 70s. Like the other (in)famous IBM language, COBOL, it doesn't care so much about space. There's no getting away from it in SQL Server I'm afraid.